# Implementing a fully-functional prototype for a web-based application

Tags: c#, php, prototyping

I am building a prototype for a web-based application and was considering building the front-end in HTML, which can then be reused later for the actual application. I had done a Flash-based prototype earlier, which embedded the .swf into a C# executable. Flash made for rapid turnaround time while the Windows application provided unlimited access to fancy API's for DB access and sound.

I want to consider something similar for this one too. Does this approach make sense? I am particularly concerned about the way the HTML would communicate with the container app. From what I understand out of preliminary research, it would be only through JavaScript, which might quickly get unwieldy. This is especially so because unlike the Flash-based prototype which implemented a lot of its functionality in the .swf, the HTML UI will depend entirely upon the shell to maintain state. Also, I don't need anything more than access to a database. So a desktop application might be overkill.

Another alternative that comes to mind is to build the prototype using PHP and deploy it with a portable server stack such as Server2Go or XAMPP. But I've never done something like this before. Anybody here shed some light on drawbacks of this approach?

The key requirement is rapid iterations of the UI, reusable front-end code and simplified deployment without any installations or configuration.

Answer (score 4):

Some of the best programming advice I've seen came from [Code Complete](http://www.cc2e.com/), and was along the lines of, "evolutionary prototypes are fine things, and throwaway prototypes are fine things, but you run into trouble when you try to make one from the other."  That is, know which type of prototype you're developing, and respect it.  If you're developing a throwaway prototype, don't permit yourself to use any of it, however tempting it may be, in the production system.  And if you're developing an evolutionary prototype - one intended to become the production system - don't compromise quality in any way.

It sounds like you're trying to get both, the rapid development of a throwaway and the reusability of an evolutionary prototype - and you can't.  Make up your mind, and stand by it.  You can't have your cake and eat it, too.

Answer (score 2):

I think you off to the wrong start, here.  Why would you want your prototype to be fully functional?  A prototype is intended to be throw-away and to help flesh out requirements and UI.  If you need full functionality, why not just skip to the final product?  If prototyping is really something you want to do, I suggest looking into a [specialized prototyping tool](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GuiPrototypingTools).

Comment: We eventually intend for the prototype to be converted into a training platform. This is a fairly specialized application built for a niche industry and hands-on training will be absolutely essential. We cannot deploy the application twice because of associated hardware and support costs. Hence, a training program which is copied to individual harddrives or run off a USB-stick is good.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. Eventually the actual app will be upgraded, but the training app will still reflect the original specs. What could the hardware/support costs of keeping a training instance really be? Plus having that training instance will save on downtime by allowing for test rollouts of upgrades first before risking taking down the actual app.

Answer (score 2):

Are you prototyping the user interface for a customer?  If you are, consider something less unwieldy like [paper prototypes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_prototypes) or presentation software (like PowerPoint) until you get the UI nailed down.  If you can establish the UI and are clear about the customer's requirements, you can then develop the application in whatever the actual platform is going to be with a clear model in mind.

In my current project, I prototyped the UI in PowerPoint first.  In a subsequent iteration, I used static web pages and some jQuery plugins to simulate actual user interaction.  That proved to be very effective in demonstrating the interface, and I didn't have to build the application first.

Answer (score 1):

I would join in on folks suggesting paper prototyping as the "idea", but not necessarily the implementation. The biggest point here is that tools such as HTML or Flash let you get "bogged down" in the details - what does this color look like? What's the text on this thing? Lots of time can pass by that way. Instead, what you should be focusing on is user flows.

One tool that keeps the spirit of paper prototyping without all the "paper" drawbacks is Balsamiq: http://www.balsamiq.com/demos/mockups/Mockups.html. It was covered by Jeff and Joel in one of the Stack Overflow podcasts; I've been using it for my own projects for a while. It's freeware, and it does its job magnificently.

Answer (score 0):

If you know C# then another option you can look at is Silverlight. You can then leverage your knowledge of C# and/or JavaScript and interact with a rich object model.

Would that do what you are looking for? The installation would be minimal on the part of the client - download and install the Silverlight plugin

Answer (score 0):

If prototyping is something you truly wish to accomplish here, paper and pencil will be your best friends. You can draw out as many iterations as necessary. While none of this is ultimately useful later on once you begin coding, it is as quick and rapid is it goes.

As mentioned previously, there are many prototyping tools which have a bit of a learning curve, but an alternative to consider would be using a framework such as CakePHP or Ruby on Rails which make for fast application logic and leave customizing the front end being the primary hard work left. And plus, you're left with a mostly functional application when you're done with your prototyping which can be tweaked as needed.

In either scenario, you're paying with your time either upfront (in the case with learning a new framework), of over time in payments (with the case of prototyping on paper or coding by hand).